# How to use base url after mod_rewrite

Tags: php, jquery, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use apache mod_rewrite to achieve the following

Change This URL:
http://mywebsite.com/products.php?id=22

to this URL
http://mywebsite.com/products/dog-house

I have everything enabled and am able to create the url, and rewrite with no problem.. The problem i have is that products.php is in the web root, and with the new rewrite rule, all my links have broke and all my jquery functions are no longer working. Because of the rewrite, it now thinks this file is in another sub directory (products), and it throws everything off

Here is a copy of my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?id=$1

</IfModule>
```

I was able to solve the problem of broken HTML links by adding this to the head tag

```
<base href="<?=BASE_URL;?>">
```

Now the problem I face is jquery.. if there was only a way to globally trick jquery to use a 'base' just like HTML gets tricked with the base tag..

Here is an example of a jquery function no longer working

```
 function search_products_by_keyword()
    {
    var keyword = $('#product_keyword').val();
    $.post('ajax/search_products_by_keyword.php', {keyword:keyword},function(data){
       $('#main_content').html(data);
    });

   }
```

I realize now that it is my fault for not thinking about using a BASE_URL in the first place. Now i have such a large amount of these jquery functions that going thru all of them 1 by 1 is a terrifying thought.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can either change your AJAX URLs to be absolute, add a rewrite for the AJAX URLs to work in the "virtual folder" `/products`, or create a `/products/ajax/search_products_by_keyword.php` that includes the correct path.

I'd prefer the second one if there's too many to fix the first.

```
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z]+)$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

Comment: or he can add another rewrite rule to rewrite AJAX  calls!

Comment: @undone That's what I meant, I edited to include the rewrite I'm suggesting.